# Why are all my incoming mails going to my junkmail?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2007

Please help me, I tried to block someone sending me messages and now all my emails are going to my junk mail folder.  Even when I try adding them or saying to accept mail from their address they still go there?  Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

Are there any Outlook rules enabled?  If so, carefully check them.  Or simply disable for a short period to test.